# Сортировка списка по полю элемента

Tags: java, android

Есть `ArrayList<ModelMusic>` с элементами `ModelMusic`:

```
public class ModelMusic implements Serializable
{
    String title;
    int count;
    String src;

    ModelMusic(String t, int c, String s){
        title=t;
        count=c;
        src=s;
    }
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
    public String getSrc(){
        return src;
    }
}
```

Как реализовать сортировку по `getCount()`.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду именно массив или список ArrayList<ModelMusic>?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сортировка списков в Java выполняется вызовом статического метода `java.util.Collections.sort(List<T> list)` для списков с элементами, реализующими `java.lang.Comparable<T>` или `java.util.Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> comparator)` для списков с любыми элементами. Для массивов есть аналогичные методы в классе `java.util.Arrays`. Сортировка изменяет порядок элементов в переданном списке.

Т.к. реализация интерфейса `Comparable` задает порядок на множестве всех объектов класса, может быть не правильно задавать такой порядок по полю `count`, поэтому я бы реализовал компаратор:

```
public class ModelMusic implements Serializable
{
    String title;
    int count;
    String src;

    ModelMusic(String t, int c, String s){
        title=t;
        count=c;
        src=s;
    }
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
    public String getSrc(){
        return src;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ModelMusic{" +
                "title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", count=" + count +
                ", src='" + src + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public static final Comparator<ModelMusic> COMPARE_BY_COUNT = new Comparator<ModelMusic>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ModelMusic lhs, ModelMusic rhs) {
            return lhs.getCount() - rhs.getCount();
        }
    };
}
```

Здесь компаратор реализован, как статическое поле класса, для удобства повторного использования. Т.к. `count`, скорее всего, небольшое неотрицательное число, можно не беспокоиться, что при вычитании произойдет переполнение, и будет возвращен неправильный результат. Если это не так, то лучше использовать `Integer.compare(int lhs, int rhs)` (доступен с API 16) или операторы сравнения.

Пример использования:

```
ArrayList<ModelMusic> songs = new ArrayList<>();
songs.add( new ModelMusic( "song 1", 8, "song1.mp3" ) );
songs.add( new ModelMusic( "song 2", 2, "song2.mp3" ) );
songs.add( new ModelMusic( "song 3", 5, "song3.mp3" ) );
songs.add( new ModelMusic( "song 4", 0, "song4.mp3" ) );

Log.i("SORTED", "pre: " + songs.toString());

Collections.sort(songs, ModelMusic.COMPARE_BY_COUNT);

Log.i("SORTED", "post: " + songs.toString() );
```

Вывод:

```
I/SORTED: pre: [ModelMusic{title='song 1', count=8, src='song1.mp3'}, ModelMusic{title='song 2', count=2, src='song2.mp3'}, ModelMusic{title='song 3', count=5, src='song3.mp3'}, ModelMusic{title='song 4', count=0, src='song4.mp3'}]
I/SORTED: post: [ModelMusic{title='song 4', count=0, src='song4.mp3'}, ModelMusic{title='song 2', count=2, src='song2.mp3'}, ModelMusic{title='song 3', count=5, src='song3.mp3'}, ModelMusic{title='song 1', count=8, src='song1.mp3'}]
```

Чтобы отсортировать список в обратном порядке, можно воспользоваться `Collections.reverseOrder`:

```
Collections.sort(songs, Collections.reverseOrder(ModelMusic.COMPARE_BY_COUNT));
```

В Java 8 было добавлено несколько новых способов работы с компараторами, например возможность строить цепочки компараторов для сравнения по нескольким полям, но Android не поддерживает Java 8.

Comment: а для чего переопределять toString()?

Comment: Для красоты в логах

Comment: проще юзать Gson

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вам нужен Comparator.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ModelMusic> modelMusicArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        //Добавление элементов

        modelMusicArrayList.add(new ModelMusic("A",1,"Whatever"));
        modelMusicArrayList.add(new ModelMusic("B",56,"Whatever"));
        modelMusicArrayList.add(new ModelMusic("C",17,"Whatever"));
        modelMusicArrayList.add(new ModelMusic("D",4,"Whatever"));
        modelMusicArrayList.add(new ModelMusic("E",2,"Whatever"));

        //Сортировка элементов

        modelMusicArrayList.sort(new Comparator<ModelMusic>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ModelMusic o1, ModelMusic o2) {
                if (o1.getCount() == o2.getCount()) return 0;
                else if (o1.getCount()> o2.getCount()) return 1;
                else return -1;
            }
        });

        //Вывод элементов

        for(int i =0 ; i<modelMusicArrayList.toArray().length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(modelMusicArrayList.get(i).getTitle()+" "+modelMusicArrayList.get(i).getCount());
        }
```

Данный код выведет следующий результат

```
A 1
E 2
D 4
C 17
B 56
```

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
public class ModelMusic implements Comparable<ModelMusic>
{
    String title;
    int count;
    String src;

    ModelMusic(String t, int c, String s){
        title=t;
        count=a;
        src=s;
    }
    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }
    public int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
    public String getSrc(){
        return src;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(ModelMusic otherModelMusic) {
        return otherModelMusic.getCount() - this.getCount();
    }
}
```

а когда нужна сортировка делаете

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

Comment: implements Comparable<ModelMusic> требует перезагрузить метод public int compare(ModelMusic о1, ModelMusic о2).  И Collections.sort(list) не принимает, пишет There is no applicable method