# Как отсортировать ArrayList<Chat> по одному из полей класса Chat?

Tags: java, android, сортировка, arraylist

Добрый день!

Есть класс Chat:

```
public class Chat {

    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String[] participants;
    private String lastMessage;
    private long created;
    private long updated;
}
```

Есть список:

```
ArrayList<Chat> chats = new ArrayList<Chat>();
```

Список содержит несколько объектов.

Необходимо отсортировать этот список по полю updated по убыванию.

Как это правильно сделать?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468248/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Видел, но адаптировать для себя не получилось.

Comment: Добавил ответ с примером.

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать `Collections.sort(...)` и `Comparator`:

```
Collections.sort(chats, new Comparator<Chat>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Chat o1, Chat o2) {
        return Long.compare(o2.getUpdated(), o1.getUpdated());
    }
});
```

Приведенную конструкцию можно упросить с помощью лямбд:

```
Collections.sort(chats, (o1, o2) -> Long.compare(o2.getUpdated(), o1.getUpdated()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Сортировка с использованием Java 8 Stream API

```
    List<Chat> collect = new ArrayList<Chat>(){{
        add(new Chat(4));
        add(new Chat(3));
        add(new Chat(6));
        add(new Chat(8));
        add(new Chat(1));
        add(new Chat(2));
    }};
    List<Chat>
        res =
        collect
            .stream()
            .sorted((f1, f2) -> Long.compare(f2.getUpdated(), f1.getUpdated()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    res.forEach(f -> System.out.println(f.getUpdated()));
```

2 вариант:

```
    collect.sort((f1, f2) -> Long.compare(f2.getUpdated(), f1.getUpdated()));
    collect.forEach(f -> System.out.println(f.getUpdated()));
```

вывод

```
8
6
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, не получилось. Android Studio ругается. Применим ли Java 8 Stream API для Android?

Comment: насколько я знаю - нет. но 2 способ должен сработать

Comment: @Miller777 Stream API можно [использовать начиная с API 24](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте компаратор для сортировки. Например:

```
class Test{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        ArrayList<Chat> chats = new ArrayList<Chat>();
        chats.add(new Chat(5));
        chats.add(new Chat(8));
        chats.add(new Chat(3));
        chats.add(new Chat(2));
        chats.add(new Chat(4));
        chats.add(new Chat(10));
        chats.add(new Chat(8));
        Collections.sort(chats, Chat.compare);
        for(Chat chat: chats)
            System.out.println(chat);
    }
}

class Chat{

    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private String[] participants;
    private String lastMessage;
    private long created;
    private long updated;

    public Chat(long updated){
        this.updated = updated;
    }

    public static final Comparator<Chat> compare = new Comparator<Chat>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Chat chat1, Chat chat2) {
            return Long.compare(chat1.updated, chat2.updated);
        }
    };

    public String toString(){
        return "Updated = " + this.updated;
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Updated = 2
Updated = 3
Updated = 4
Updated = 5
Updated = 8
Updated = 8
Updated = 10
```

За основу взят этот ответ:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468299/235436

Comment: Благодарю, заработало! Пришлось поднять min. API level с 16 до 19, иначе Android Studio ругалась.